# String[] method returns a not-null java

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, porting

I recently ported my eclipse project to IJ recently and my array randomizer returns following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at Constants.func.ranArr(func.java:42)
```

and

```
(String[]) i.toArray();in func.ranArr(String[])(filter not-null)
```

this is the code of the method

```
    public static String[] ranArr(String[] arr) {
        List<String> i = Arrays.asList(arr);
        Collections.shuffle(i);
        String[] r = (String[]) i.toArray();
        return r;
    }
```

How do I fix it, it worked in Eclipse

Comment: Make sure that your intellijidea uses the same jdk to run as eclipse

Comment: Yes its the same JDK Java SE-1.8

Comment: This does not run in Eclipse. It gives exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `(String[]) i.toArray()` by `i.toArray(new String[0])`.

Comment: Yes, It worked, but why would it work and eclipse and not IJ?

Comment: Pretty sure that it does not depend on your IDE because it happens at the runtime. Unfortunately, I don't use Eclipse to reproduce and look deeply.

Answer (score 0):

Because an ArrayList can store items of any type, internally it uses a `Object[]` to store the array's contents.

When you call `toArray()`, it simply returns a copy of that internal array, which is again an `Object[]`.

In fact, because of type erasure (the fact that an instance of a generic type doesn't know at runtime what type its type parameters are) the `ArrayList` can't do anything else.

As you know that you are storing Strings, you can use `toArray(new String[0])`, as @Timur suggested.

That function will look at the type of the array you pass and create a new array with that type.